# C++ can I initialize member variable based on a just initialized another member variable?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I initialize member variable `a`, can I immediately read the value of `a` to initialize `b`?

Is this guaranteed by C++(11) specifications to work always with all compilers?

Is there any side effect?

E.g:

```
class X {
   public:
   int a;
   int b;  
   X() : a(1), b(a+1) {}
};
```

Comment: Looks good to me. But note that the order that matters is the order of member variables in the class. `X() : b(1), a(b+1) {}` would not be correct.

Comment: Yes, it's fine, but beware that order in initialization list doesn't matter - members are initialized in order of declaration in class.